# Yii2 Pjax не работает

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Ставлю `advanced` шаблон `Yii2` через `composer`:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application`

Далее через `Gii` генерирую модель по таблице `test` (она уже заранее существует в бд). После чего, в `Gii` перехожу в раздел `CRUD Generator`, заполняю все поля следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Галочку `Enable Pjax` поставил.

Далее генерирую все это, открываю созданный контроллер в браузере, вижу стандартную `CRUD` страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В инпуте фильтра по полю `Password` ввожу что-нибудь (например, "6")... и... после потери инпутом фокуса, страница перезагружается полностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На вышеприведенном скрине видно, что опять подгружаюся `JS` и `CSS` файлы. Что странно - первый запрос не отрабатывает, и как будто бы перебивается вторым. По каким причинам `Pjax`не срабатывает? Я в код сам не лез от слова совсем, генерировал все через `Gii`.

Содержимое первого запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что в `GET` параметре передается `_pjax=#p0`

Ответа на первый запрос нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь уже этого параметра нет.

Ответ от сервера по второму запросу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что приходит вся страница целиком. Ходя должна прийти только обновляемая `Pjax`'ом часть.

`Gif` того, как это работает сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как починить `Pjax` и заставить подгружать только часть страницы, а не всю страницу целиком?

Comment: Ссылки на сгенерированные `Gii` файлы:

`TestController.php` контроллер - https://pastebin.com/c2HX8E1E

`Test.php` модель - https://pastebin.com/SpwxQxkN

`TestSearch.php` модель - https://pastebin.com/tp0Zx9Mb

`_form.php` view - https://pastebin.com/bqAeHvgF

`_search.php` view - https://pastebin.com/jeg4eUcS
`create.php` view - https://pastebin.com/2HQYff8p

`index.php` view - https://pastebin.com/axWDwLWu

`update.php` view - https://pastebin.com/N2JvBBh4

`view.php` view - https://pastebin.com/mXhKwXpu

Comment: Какая-то странная ситуация. В коде я ошибок не нашёл, тогда начнём предполагать. Добавьте 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true] внутрь $form = ActiveForm::begin(). Как тут в примере: [https://webformyself.com/yii2-activeform-chast-5/]